# Detecting a timed out Callable instance

Tags: java, callable

I am performing some operations that are time sensitive and have a timeout associated with them.

This timeout mechanism is implemented using the Java Callable class.

The problem is that within the callable instance I execute an asynchronous task, with an anonymous interface implementation (listener).

My problem is that when the timeout triggers and the callable is cancelled. The async callback still executes and corrupts the state of my program.

How do I prevent these callbacks from firing? Do I just include a boolean specififying whether or not the timeout has ocurred or is there another way of achieving this please?

Thanks.

Code reference:

```
Callable<Object> callableTransaction = new Callable<Object>() {

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {

        Callback callback = new Callback() {

            // Do stuff here and change program state.
        };

        performAsyncOperation(callback);

        return ActionProcessor.OPERATION_COMPLETE;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you remove performAsyncOperation and perform the operation synchronously inside the call method.

And then, if you need any async operation, you can invoke your callableTransaction using performAsyncOperation or executor services.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Callable` in a [`java.util.concurrent.FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html)... call [`task.cancel(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#cancel(boolean)) when you want to cancel things. If your `Callable` is in a blocking operation (I/O, for example), then an exception will be thrown marking the interruption. Otherwise, your thread will need to check using [`Thread.isInterrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted()) periodically to see if it should continue or abort.

Yes, this is mostly the same as including your own `boolean` flag, but you do get the benefit of blocking operations getting interrupted as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea:  Use a boolean flag to track whether the Callable has been interrupted.  (I'm assuming that when you cancel the Callable, you are specifying that it should be interrupted.)

Use a concurrent class like [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to make your Callable behave synchronously:

```
public Object call() throws Exception {

    final AtomicBoolean aborted = new AtomicBoolean();
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    Callback callback = new Callback() {

        if (aborted.get()) {
            return;
        }

        // Do stuff here and change program state.

        latch.countDown();  // Tell Callable we're done.
    };

    performAsyncOperation(callback);

    try {
        latch.await();      // Wait for callback to finish.
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        aborted.set(true);
    }

    return ActionProcessor.OPERATION_COMPLETE;
}
```